# Minifigure Torso Cracks

Tags: minifigures, star-wars, repair, replacement-parts

So I recently picked up the new Star Wars AT-AP and I was quite please with what I got, but after not even a week The awesome Commander Gree Figure had a torso crack that went from the bottom of the left side to About halfway to the top. It was put together and put on a shelf. No kids played with it or anything.

Is this because of the legs stretching it out or has the quality of LEGO decreased? Also how can I fix this without using glue?

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of [Repairing LEGO minifigure torso cracks/damage](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1478/repairing-lego-minifigure-torso-cracks-damage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that this is from a new set that is currently in production, you should contact LEGO customer service and they'll probably send you a replacement torso at no charge. LEGO has a pretty simple site to handle this:

https://service.lego.com/en-us/replacementparts#BasicInfo

You just have to enter your age and the issue that you are having, then you enter the set number (75043 in this case) and find the piece that is broken from the parts list. I just checked, and that torso is currently listed, so you should be in good shape. I've had this same torso issue, and they were happy to send a replacement.