# Removing glue from Lego bricks

Tags: glue

When I was five my Dad used some kind of a good glue to put together a set together so I didn't loose any pieces. Putting the ethics of that action aside, I want to split the bricks from another and remove the glue. I tried heating up the set in boiling water but the glue didn't budge. Any ideas out there?

Comment: Unfortunately, knowing **which** kind of glue was used might be a crucial piece of information. And some may be impossible to remove altogether (Methyl-Ethyl-Ketone like [they use in LEGOland parks](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/1038/99), for example, as it fuses bricks together)

Comment: See also [this answer](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/165) regarding glue.

Comment: And why do we even have a tag [tag:glue] anyway?

Comment: Put them in fire. Sure, it will melt the LEGO parts bricks but it will also get the glue off.

Comment: Don't remove the glue at all. What your dad glued up back then is now a relic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tough job.

You can *try* using some nail polish remover to try to start breaking down the glue.

From [Removing Super Glue](http://www.supergluecorp.com/removingsuperglue.html), which they give for advice for people that accidentally glue their fingers together, this procedure *might* also work for the bricks.

> ...even though Super Glue is incredibly strong, it has one weakness: acetone.
>
> Acetone is often found in household nail polish remover, and a small amount on the end of a Q-tip or cotton swab applied directly to the glue should dissolve the bond without damaging the skin.

A lot will depend obviously on how much glue was used inside the bricks, but perhaps a little crack and a small screw driver to help pry them apart and keep applying the acetone to the reachable edges can help break them apart.

I don't know if acetone will do something to the brick's color or structure, so proceed carefully.

Good luck.

Comment: Yes, be very careful with acetone as it's been shown previously to ideal for melting bricks together

Comment: Please, DO NOT USE acetone!!! I used it on some legos and the lego pretty much MELTED. DO NOT USE ACETONE!!!

Comment: @Kaylee yes, for images look towards the end of the [this article](http://thebrickblogger.com/2011/01/lego-glued-magnet-removal/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, maybe you could try using a nail in between the bricks. I personally have never glued legos together, so I am just giving an idea. Odd, right?

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Non acetone nail polish remover is used to remove glue and polish bit notnharm artificial nails. It's used tonremove pitch from cars without harming paint. After reading this, I guess it's about my only hope.