# What element is this a piece of, and how can I repair it?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification, repair

Yesterday, as I was putting away some Lego, I saw the following obviously broken piece.

[image: broken lego]
[image: more broken lego]

I couldn't figure out what element this was a piece of, so I was all ready to ask it here, when I came across the other part.

So instead of a genuine question, I'll post it as a challenge. First one to find the element this is a part of, gets a bonus (which I'll set and award as soon as possible).

> [image: solution]

That leaves me with the question how to repair this, if possible.

Comment: We've covered some [repair](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1037/56) [techniques](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/2870/56) already here which should work for light use - but you may find that no repair will give you the full torque allowance the part had previously.

Comment: Also, you could use the two pin holes to attach a gear to the wheel, and use that to support the axle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's difficult to tell exactly what part this fragment came from, but it looks like it is part of a broken Technic gear or pulley. It looks like it probably came from 3736:

[image: 3736]

Your fragment looks like it was probably once one half of the center axle hole of that part.

In terms of repair, I suppose you could try to glue this back together, but given that the part was likely bent as well as broken, this is unlikely to work well. Luckily, this part is common, abundant, and cheap, so it's trivial to [replace via Bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/search.asp?q=3736) if you are so inclined.

If this part broke under relatively normal conditions, you could also request a replacement via [LEGO customer service](https://service.lego.com/en-us/replacementparts). I've done this in the past for parts that have broken while building, and TLG has been happy to ship me replacements at no cost.

Comment: This Technic part was one of the easiest to break, due to the structural weak point that was intended to facilitate insertion of a cross axle. I broke at least a couple as a kid.