# Preparations for outside display

Tags: building, durability

I am thinking of using LEGO to make some outside yard art, (large minifig scale castle) and wondered what I should do to prepare them for being outside in variable weather conditions (in the Seattle area).

I am aware that Legoland glues their displays, but have not found any other details on their technique.

Discoloring in the sun is not a big concern of mine, other than I will probably avoid too many white elements which tend to discolor more noticeably.

As it's ABS plastic I imagine water wouldn't be a problem, and I should just be able to wash them down if they get dirty.  What about snow/ice freezing temperatures?

Does anyone have any experience with outdoor displays?

Comment: Check out another post here: http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/what-glue-should-i-use-for-permanent-lego-construction/1038#1038  that asks a specific question about glue.

Answer (score 5):

I once talked with a Lego Builder at the Florida park. He told me they use a glue that actually melts the Lego blocks together. With that in mind, I searched and found [this article (on Facebook)](https://www.facebook.com/notes/official-legoland-windsor/your-questions-answered-by-legoland-model-maker-nev-smith-part-2/497439006912). It says Lego Park Model Makers

> use a solvent based plastic weld. It heats the bricks up so the edges bind together. Obviously it has to be very strong to withstand weather conditions.

A quick search on that found [this from Google shopping](https://www.google.com/search?q=solvent+based+plastic+weld&oq=solvent+based+plastic+weld&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=solvent+based+plastic+weld&tbm=shop).

The article also talks about color fading and model life time (about 5 to 7 years), after which the model can either be rebuilt or cleaned:

> We clean them using a shot blasting technique. They are sprayed with a fine salt spray, which takes a very thin layer off the bricks, and then they are lacquered with a UV coating. This gives them another 3 years or so.

I hope the project goes well.

Comment: good link, I've seen more info on how the LEGO parks glue their models, [here](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/what-glue-should-i-use-for-permanent-lego-construction/1038#1038) but this one mentioned they spray models with a clear UV coating, and gave some outside display lifetime estimates (5-7 years) also mentions salt water shot blast refurbishment method.  Thanks