# How can I separate 1 x 1 round from boat mast base 4 x 4?

Tags: disassembly

I have two pieces I cannot seem to separate. The parts in question are:

- 3062b: Brick, Round 1 x 1 Open Stud
- 6067: Black Boat Mast Section Base 4 x 4 x 1 2/3

The 1 x 1 is transparent in this case, in case that makes a difference (I think the plastic type is different for transparent pieces).

The center of the mast base fits snuggly inside the 1 x 1. The outer wall of the mast base blocks access to the bottom lip of the 1 x 1. There is a hole through the bottom of the mast base, but it's narrow enough that if I try to stick a 3957 antenna through it, the tip of the antenna doesn't catch the top lip on the inside of the 1 x 1 round. I tried pinching the top of the 1 x 1 and wiggling it, but it is too tight.

Separate:

[image]
[image]

Assembled:

[image]

Comment: [Transparent pieces are made of a different plastic.](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/191/what-kind-of-plastic-are-lego-bricks-made-of) As I recall, the transparent ones do have a tendency to stick harder, especially against other transparent pieces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a straightened paperclip pushed through the hole in the mast from the bottom? You could put a small piece of paper in first so that it'll catch on the 1x1 on the way out.

Comment: Success. The paperclip catches the edge as expected. I had to try twice. I think the second push was from a different side.