# How can I use System and Bionicle elements together?

Tags: compatibility, bionicle

I have a small collection of Bionicle elements that I would like to incorporate into my System builds but I am a little unsure how to use them.

What are the different ways to use these two types of bricks together?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

since the bionicle-pieces only have holes for technic-connections and no studs to use then directly with bricks, you'll have two possibilities:

- build some kind of "adapter" using technic-pieces. you could use [pegs](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=139) to connect the bionicle-piece with some kind of [technic-brick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catID=135).
- put the studs of your system-bricks into the bionicle-pieces technic-holes - which [may not be the best idea](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/203/when-did-lego-decide-that-it-was-okay-to-put-a-stud-into-a-technic-hole)

I'd prefer the first option - it's easy, more robust, not controversial and just need two or three pieces in most cases. for example a [brick with axle-hole](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=32064) and a [small axle](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3704) or a [brick with hole](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6541) and a [simple peg](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=4459a) is all you need to get started.

Answer (score 3):

As oezi says, Bionicle elements are usually compatible with Technic connections only, but there are quite a lot of system bricks which have Technic connections as well.

As for what to do with Bionicle elements, only your own imagination can answer that. Once you've an idea about what a specific Bionicle element is going to represent in your creation, how to connect it is usually not the biggest issue. So, go surprise us!

Of course, some green Bionicle elements are best used in wilderness, as they have "wild" shapes — allowing you a little more freedom than if you wanted to build buildings. Giant weapons on the other hand may become a cool building decoration.

The best example I can think of is [this palmtree](http://uniquebriquetechniques.blogspot.com/2006/05/gasp.html) which is just brilliant.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Bionicle mask connection]

You can also attach the first generation Bionicle masks using their, 'stud,' joint, the second generation masks are a bit looser, and the later masks have Technic connections.

I have only ever used this to provide a texture at the front of a spaceship, but if you have the right masks you could use the gaps to create gun covers, etc.