# How much heat can LEGO bricks withstand?

Tags: durability, plastics

I was thinking on making a decorative LEGO candle holder. It would be made out of regular ABS LEGO bricks, but also transparent ones. Because there will be an open flame involved, I want to make sure my LEGO bricks don't melt.

How much heat can LEGO bricks withstand?

Comment: You might consider using an LED imitation "flameless" candle. These come in different sizes that may fit your idea, and some even have a wax exterior.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

- ABS maximum temperature is 80°C (176°F) and melt at 105°C (221°F)
- Polycarbonate plastic used for transparent bricks melt at 267°C (512.6°F)

Since a candle flame has a temperature in excess of 1000°C (1832°F). I would advise against making a candle holder of LEGO bricks.

Plastic types are explained on this [question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/155/are-transparent-neon-lego-bricks-made-from-a-different-plastic-than-usual).

Comment: ABS melting at 105C/220F is most likely the reason why LEGO discourage the dishwasher for cleaning bricks.

Comment: And it should be noted that ABS can deform under much lower heat than even 80C. Even direct sunlight on a hot summer day can warp parts.

Answer (score 5):

I had Lego MOCs loose their clutch on me after being left in a car for 9 hours during the summer.  Outside temp was about 100F, so inside was quite a bit hotter.  After this, I had to glue the MOCs back together.

So, the shorter answer is that I'd imagine that a candle could damage the plastics at least to the point where the bricks would not hold together very well.