# Is it safe to use a hot glue gun for Mega Bloks?

Tags: 3rd-party, glue

I've just managed to secure a copy of the Mega Bloks StarCraft Battlecruiser set on eBay after they dropped significantly in value with Blizzard clearing out the last of the stock with their recent Black Friday sale. It's going to be here in about a week, and it's the first model of this magnitude that I've ever done. I figure that the actual process won't be any more difficult than usual, but considering the collectible nature of this item, I'd like to make sure that when I put it together, it's permanent.

Is it safe to use a hot glue gun? Naturally, I wouldn't want to try it and find the bricks melting under the heat. I would just test it on some more easily replaced pieces, but I currently don't have any Mega Bloks in my collection, only LEGO elements and Tyco.

Comment: You mention the "collectible" nature of the item. I can assure you that after you glue it, the only collector who'll want it is you. Nothing devalues a building toy like glue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably not the best option to use no: according to Wikipedia, [glue guns tend to operate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot-melt_adhesive#Glue_gun_specifications_and_usage) at the following temperatures:

> Low-temperature glue guns operate at approximately 120°C (248°F) [...] High-temperature guns operate at approximately 190°C (374 °F)

LEGO and Mega Bloks' primary component, ABS, [has a melting point around 105°C (221°F)](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/547/56), which is a bit lower than the glue and it will have started to deform around 80°C (176°F).

Your best option would be to use [a glue that "welds"](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1037/56) the LEGO elements together, such as Plastic or Polystyrene Cement.

Comment: @Zaph - Disappointing to hear, but certainly beats finding out the hard way. I'll pick up some plastic cement next time I'm at Hobby Lobby. Thank you for your time.